# no out-of-line virtual method definitions for full-specialized template class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, clang

I have this kind of structure:

**static lib A**

> interface.h

```
class Interface
{
   public:
   virtual ~Interface() // no pure virtual dtor

   virtual void pureMethod1() = 0;
   virtual void pureMethod2() = 0;

   virtual void virtualMethod1();
   virtual void virtualMethod2();
};
```

> interface.cpp

```
include "interface.h"
Interface::~Interface() = default;
Interface::virtualMethod1() {}
Interface::virtualMethod2() {}
```

**static lib B using A**

> BaseT.h

```
#include "interface.h"
template<class T>
class BaseT final : public Interface
{
   static_assert(false, "can't use this specialization");
};
```

> specialized1.h

```
#include "baset.h"

using MyType = BaseT<CustomClass1>;

template<>
class BaseT<CustomClass1> : public Interface
{
public:
   BaseT() = default;

   void pureMethod1() final {}
   void pureMethod2() final {}
};
```

> specialized2.h

```
#include "baset.h"

using MyType = BaseT<CustomClass2>;

template<>
class BaseT<CustomClass2> : public Interface
{
public:
   BaseT() = default;

   void pureMethod1() final {}
   void pureMethod2() final {}
};
```

I'm receiving a warning from clang in both fully specialized classes:

*warning: 'BaseT has no out-of-line virtual method definition: its vtable will be emitted in every translation unit'*

Why this warning? I don't have any pure virtual destructor, and a defaulted one is provided in base class. And how I can avoid the out-of-line virtual method since I'm using a template?

Comment: You should simplify this code to make an mcve. Right now it won't compile because of static_assert  failure and other issues.

Comment: @PasserBy that is a different question

Comment: @V.Kravchenko Yeah my mistake, didn't read it through.

Comment: The only problem is that all the object files will be slightly larger. There will still only be one vtable in the executable. The linker takes care of that (but will perhaps take a bit longer to sort it all out).

Comment: `static_assert(false, "can't use this specialization");` makes your code ill formed, you have to do something like `template <typename T> struct always_false : std::false_type {}; static_assert(always_false<T>::value, "can't use this specialization");` (which seems similar but is correct).

Comment: @Jarod42 you're right, it was simplified

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The resloution of virtual functions is usually implemented by the use of a table of function pointers, the vtable. Each class implementing (i.e. inheriting from) the interface have such a table where the entries points to its implementation of the vitual functions. This table must be located in at least one of the object files generated during compilation and by default many compilers put it in the object file containing the implementation of the first virtual function in the class.

In your case all virtual functions in the specializations of `BaseT` are defined inline in the class declaration. In this case there is no unique object file to put their implementation in, they will be included in all object files where it is used. This in turn implies that the method of putting the vtable together with the implementation of the first virtual function will no longer work. This makes the compiler fall back to add a version of the vtable to all object files just to be safe and to make the programmer aware of this it issues a warning.

This is not really a problem since the linker will choose the vtable from one of the object files and include in the final binary.

Answer (score 4):

This warning occurs, because your virtual function implementation is located in a header file.

Header files are just pasted inside ccp-files with `#include` directive. So your file will be pasted into multiple cpp-files. And as implementation is provided inside class, it's separate for each cpp-file. Therefore, for each object files all instantiations will be generated

There is no simple way to avoid that, but there are a few possible solutions. The simple solution is finding single cpp that uses the implementation.
Another workaround is just getting rid of templates in place where the methods are implemented, i.e

```
class ImplForCustomClass2 : public Interface
{
public:
    virtual void pureMethod1() final override;
    virtual void pureMethod2() final override;
};
template<>
class Base<CustomClass2> : public ImplForCustomClass2
{};
```

There are more ways to avoid it, though. You can try finding a way that suits you more.

Comment: The pure virtual method implementation is strictly bounded to the template argument, so sadly I can't do that

Comment: @Moia Sorry for being unclear, but you can! You need just to create Impl-class for every possible valid template argument and make this inheritance from implementation thing for every BaseT-class template instantiation

Comment: sorry I don't understand. I can't implement `puremethod1` in `implForCustomClass2` since the implementation depends from `CustomClass2` with an object stored in `Base<CustomClass2>`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah. Well, as I understood, you wrote that `CustomClass2` object is stored in `Base<CustomClass2>`. It's not true. `Base<CustomClass2>` only constains information, that implementation is for `T`=`CustomClass2`. I'm trying to say that `ImplForCustomClass2` is implementation of the interface `Interface` with the same `pureMethod1` and `pureMethod2` implementations, as you were going to write in `specialized2.h` in your example. `ImplForCustomClass2` is exactly the same class as `Base2<CustomClass2>` in your example, but without a template, which allows it's methods to be implemented in cpp.

Comment: I mean, for `CustomClass1` you would write `ImplForCustomClass1` with corresponding implementations of methods for `CustomClass1`, and then just do inheritance `class TBase<CustomClass1> : public ImplForCustomClass1`.
Again, it's not the only workaround, there may by other solutions to avoid your problem